# PHP - Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in

Tags: php

I'm creating a dynamic list of fonts to choose from in a select-menu on one of my pages, linked to a text-field.

Using the script below, this works perfectly fine, however, if the text-field is left blank, the select-menu shows me this error message:

> **Warning:** Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in
>   **/opt.php** on line
>   **373**

In the `/opt.php` file on line 373:

```
else {
    foreach ($decode['items'] as $key => $value) {
        $item_family = $decode['items'][$key]['family'];
        $item_family_trunc =  str_replace(' ','+',$item_family);        
        $default[$item_family_trunc] = $item_family;
    }
}
```

As I'm new to PHP, how would I be able to fix the above script so that I am no longer getting the error message when the text-field is left blank?

Thank you.

Comment: Is `$decode['items']` an array?

Comment: can u var_dump($decode['items']); just above 373?

Comment: check if you get the data in print_r($decode);

Comment: This is a duplicate of **every single question in the Related sidebar**.  Please, *please* review the recommended related questions when creating your questions.  There are *two* lists of these while you create your question.  The first is between the question title and body, and the second is big, fat, orange, and lives to the right of the question body.

Comment: No, it's not the same @Charles.  Thank you though...

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the argument for the `foreach` loop is an array by using `is_array()` function

```
if (isset($decode['items']) && is_array($decode['items'])) {
    foreach ($decode['items'] as $key => $value) {
        $item_family = $decode['items'][$key]['family'];
        $item_family_trunc =  str_replace(' ','+',$item_family);        
        $default[$item_family_trunc] = $item_family;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

With

```
if(empty($decode)) {
```

You are only checking whether $decode is empty or not, as opposed to whether it has 'items' set.

```
if (!isset($decode['items']) && is_array($decode['items'])) {
```

may work better.

Also within your foreach loop you can just reference the $value rather than try to traverse the array. so..

```
$item_family_trunc =  str_replace(' ','+',$value['family']);
```

Comment: `isset() && is_array()` will check to see if the variable exists and, if it does, will then check if it is an array. `is_array()` will only check if `$decode['items']` is an array. It's just a fallback really.

Answer (score 2):

You need to ensure that `decode['items']` isset, is an array, and not empty:

```
$decode = json_decode($json, true);
if(empty($decode)) {

}elseif(isset($decode['items']) && !empty($decode['items']) && is_array($decode['items'])){
            foreach ($decode['items'] as $key => $value) {
            $item_family = $decode['items'][$key]['family'];
            $item_family_trunc =  str_replace(' ','+',$item_family);        
            $default[$item_family_trunc] = $item_family;

        }
    }   
}
```

The problem with your code is that it may be possible that `$decode` is not empty (error message, etc), and so you need to ensure that `$decode['items']` is available.